# ArcIMS equivalent in QGIS for adding images from external client

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am looking to add some images to the QGIS map canvas from an external server. My client has provided their server URL to access their data (with password credentials). The instructions to access the URL using ArcGIS (via ArcIMS) is also given.

But I want to access the URL and view the image layers from their server in QGIS. Is there any option available to access the URL in QGIS and to add the images in QGIS map canvas?

Or is there any way to develop stand-alone python plugin to achieve this? I had a glance at OpenLayers Plugin python code where they access the Google Physical layer using

```
OlGoogleMapsLayer.__init__(self, name="Google Physical", html="google_physical.html")
```

Is there a similar way to access ArcIMS layer using python?

Comment: ArcIMS?  That's a seriously ancient interface.  Esri would retain reverse compatibility, but since it predates QGIS, there's no reason QGIS would.